# Equivalent of Phonegap Emulator App for Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

Phonegap has an [app](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/2-install-mobile-app/) that lets you easily test your app on your phone. Does Cordova have an equivalent?

Also, I have read about the [difference](http://blog.ionic.io/what-is-cordova-phonegap/)between Cordova and Phonegap, but I still don't understand in practice. When I start a Phone Gap app, should it have all the capabilities of Cordova PLUS Phonegap extras, or am I understanding wrong.

Adding ionic and other libraries to a phonegap project seems to crash it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sadly it doesn't have an emulator which you can test it on your own device easily, instead what you can do is either:

1. `build` the app and run it on your device
   or
2. or `emulate` in the `Android-Emulator`

to use the emulator, you to download and install android SDK (software developer kit) from here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html (android studio includes the android sdk)

then you can install the desire phone/tablet emulator... in the cordova command line, you can then enter this command:

```
$ cordova emulate android
```

and it will pop open the android emulator with you app open and ready to be tested!

When using the Android SDK, you will not be required to build your cordova app, and everything will be done locally on your computer, although the app will behave as if it were on a real android device!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.